# Returning an image that is not stored locally with a flask endpoint

Tags: python, flask, urllib, flask-restful

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate, I've seen plenty of questions on returning an image from a flask endpoint but what happens when the photo you're trying to return resides remotely? Eg, in an S3 bucket?

Originally my code returns an image from a python flask endpoint when there is a GET request.

```
class ReturnImage(Resource):

    def get(self):
        #Some code here

        full_file_path = '/local/home/pic.gif'

        return send_file(full_file_path,mimetype='image/gif')
```

Except that only works when the image `pic.gif` is stored locally on my machine. If I now want to return an image that is not stored locally, how do I do it? I tried to use `urllib` library to download the image and then return the output of that but doesn't seem to do the trick. Below is my attempt,

```
import urllib.request

class ReturnImage(Resource):

    def get(self):
        #Some code here

        full_file_path = '/local/home/pic.gif'
        image = urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/pic.gif")

        return send_file(image,mimetype='image/gif')
```

Comment: you may checkout this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52345423/10845016